# Windows XP will not remember a share's password after reboot

Tags: windows-xp, samba, mapped-drive, net-use

I mounted a mapped drive from a server; it was set to automatically map this on every reboot, and it was set up to remembered the password, and everything was great.  For a long time, I didn't have any problems.

But now, I had to change the server hosting the share.  I kept the same IP address, but I changed the login name for the share.   Now, Windows always complain "Incorrect password or unknown username" even after I remapped the drive and entered the new username and password.  Now, even if I start from scratch, it won't remember the password even if I ask it to.

1. Starting with no mapped drives and an empty "Stored User Names and Passwords" in the `"control keymgr.dll"` Key Manager.
2. Next, I mapped a shared drive.  I made sure to check the boxes "Reconnect at logon" and "Remember my password".
   [screenshot for #1 and #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hyh18.png)
3. Drive is then mapped and everything works fine for this session.
4. However, the problem is after a reboot, it prompts for a password when I access the mapped drive.
   [screenshot for #3 and #4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TohZ9.png)
5. I have tried using `"net use Z: \\192.168.0.208\share /savecred /persistent:yes"` but it still has the same problem after a reboot.  I also tried using `"cmdkey /add:192.168.0.208 /user:192.168.0.208\vmware /pass:<PASSWORD>"` but it doesn't fix this problem either.  It always prompts like this after a reboot.
6. I tried searching the forums but in every case, the suggestion is to do a `"net use /savecred"` or "cmdkey" but these don't work for me.  I also can't use a startup bat file that calls `"net use Z: \\192.168.0.208\share <PASSWORD>"` because other people can access my PC and can see the password stored in plain text.

I would appreciate any help on this problem.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add or remove(wrong password) password manually.
To Add or Remove cached credentials

1. Click Start and select Run
2. In the Open field type "rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr"
3. Once the Stored Usernames and Passwords interface opens you can select any of the entries and select Properties to view the existing information
4. To remove a saved password you can select one of the entries and select Remove. A confirmation screen will appear. Click on OK and the account will be removed
5. You can add additional saved passwords as well by clicking on the Add button and entering the appropriate information
6. Repeat the steps above as needed to add, remove or edit saved passwords
7. When you are done using the interface click the Close button
   [Removing Saved Credentials (passwords) from Windows XP](https://www.interworks.com/blog/jvalente/2010/02/02/removing-saved-credentials-passwords-windows-xp-windows-vista-or-windows-7)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.  Did you see the two screenshots?  I already removed all the saved passwords and started over from scratch.  I then saved the right password in the Key Manager, but after a reboot, it still has the error.

Comment: You have to save it with address name instead of ip because your ip might be change in restart.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, what I did was I reconfigure my samba server configuration at `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and put `'netbios name = servername'` maximum of 15 chars only and without quotation of course.

Then I disconnect all the mapped drives from Windows XP machines and remapped those network drives and reboot the machines then that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this problem be connecting the drive automatically if it is not already mapped upon logon. You can do this with Group Policy, Task Scheduler, or by placing it in the startup folder. (since you said no startup folder, you can use the other two)

Create this file in notepad and save it as logon.bat

```
     @echo off
     net use z: \\server\share\folder user:usernamehere password:passwordhere
```

For Group Policy, assign a logon script and select the file you created.
For Task Scheduler, create a new task, define the trigger as logon, and define the action as running the batch file you created.

To avoid the startup folder security problem, you can also add your username to the shared folder's permissions. This might not work if you don't have a domain.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't use this solution, because other people can access my PC and can see the password stored in plain text (item #6 in my list).  I appreciate your help.

Comment: Who are the other people accessing this PC? Do you have a domain? Who has access to the server you are connecting to? And finally, do you also mean that they can go into your Documents and Settings folder?

Comment: It's accessible to my brother, his friends who come over, etc, basically anyone who comes in the house. The PC doesn't have a domain because it is just a home computer.  By default it is in WORKGROUP which is a Windows workgroup.  The 'server' is the family NAS appliance which runs samba, we all have separate logins to mount our personal share.  Since this is a Windows PC, and all logins have "Administrator" access, other people can definitely get into my "Documents" folder.  Which is why I keep all my files on the mapped drive.

Comment: Well, then anyone could login to your account and access your files then, right? So maybe it's good that you need to re-enter your credentials each time; anyone could access them if they reconnected each time

Answer (score 0):

When I map a drive, I do it via the Map network drive option where you have the checkbox Remember my credentials.

It will then remember this at login

[image]